# Jenkins: how to run builds in unique directories

Tags: jenkins

I am configuring Jenkins for the first time, have been a user of it until now.

I read the documentation and understand what "$WORKSPACE" means on the **slave**.

I had a misconception that by **default** the jobs on Jenkins Slave run in a unique directory per job inside the workspace directory. This doesnt seem to be the case.

How do I assign a unique directory per job run?
Will Jenkins automatically cleanup this job run directory after its done?

Comment: Have you read the help text associated with the "Execute concurrent builds" option in your Jenkins job? It explains Jenkins' behavior. If you still have questions, please describe your job configuration and what you've tried so someone can reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default jenkins runs from `$WORKSPACE/JOB Name` ; here WORKSPACE is defined in the node configuration. This could be changed by choosing `Advance Project options` -> `Use custom workspace` under your job configuration.

Regarding cleanup: Choose `Build Environment` -> `Delete workspace before build starts` under jobs configuration if you like to cleanup for each new job.

Comment: So by default, all the build runs are done in "$WORKSPACE/JOB Name"? I am bit confused as to how Jenkins handles concurrent runs of the same Job.

Comment: @sam in case you enable concurrent execution for a job, then Jenkins will indeed create unique directories for the different runs.

Comment: For concurrent builds on the same node, Jenkins will create build folder name with @<number> to keep it unique. Note that @ char can be problematic if something in your code uses absolute path converted to URI (as @ is special char in URI). There is a way to change it by system property hudson.slaves.WorkspaceList (supplied in command which starts Jenkins): check Jenkins docs: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties and Jenkins issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11519

Comment: And apparently in Multi-Branch pipeline jobs, that option is not available but the "concurrent execution" is enabled by default. If the pipeline should be executed sequentially the line `properties([disableConcurrentBuilds()])` should be used in the jenkinsfile.

Comment: Where exactly is the Advance Project options? I can not see it in the job configuration.

Comment: @BalajiVignesh was struggling with this one as well. enter the configuration of the single job, under the "General" tab, click the "Advanced" button to reveal additional options. now you should see the "Use custom workspace" option. the value i configured that worked for me was: ${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}

Comment: sorry, can't edit my comment. but for those looking for the path, use this one instead of what i wrote (should prevent permission issues): ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace/${BUILD_NUMBER}

Answer (score -2):

Jenkins will create workspace directory by default if jobs is successfully executed at-least once

Comment: There are two questions and you haven't answered the second one: Will Jenkins automatically cleanup this job run directory after its done?

Comment: jenkins will not clean up job space and workspace directory. you can do it by checking before next build starts .

Comment: The way this sentence is structured it makes no sense to me.