# Jenkins is re-using a pipeline workspace and I wish for each build to have a unique workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

So, most of the questions and answers I've found on this subject is for people who want to use the SAME workspace for different runs.  (Which baffles me, but then I require a clean slate each time I start a job.  Leftover stuff will only break things)

My issue is the EXACT opposite - I *MUST* have a separate workspace for each run (or I need to know how to create files with the same name in different runs that stay with that run only, and which are easily reachable from bash scripts started by the pipeline!)

So, my question is - how do I either force Jenkins to NOT use the same workspace for two concurrently-running jobs on different hosts, OR what variable can I use in the 'custom workspace' field to accomplish this?

After I responded to the question by @Joerg S I realized that I'm saying the thing that Joerg S says CAN'T happen is EXACTLY what I'm observing!  Jenkins is using the SAME workspace for 2 different, concurrent, jobs on 2 different hosts.  **Is this a Jenkins pipeline bug?**

See below for a bewildering amount of information.

Given the way I have to go onto and off of nodes during the run, I've found that I can start 2 different builds on different hosts of the same job, and they SHARE the workspace dir!  Since each job has shell scripts which are busy writing files into that directory, this is extremely bad.

In [Custom workspace in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537137/custom-workspace-in-jenkins) we are told to use custom workspace, and I'm set up just like that

In [Jenkins: how to run builds in unique directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207067/jenkins-how-to-run-builds-in-unique-directories) we are told to use ${BUILD_NUMBER} in the above custom workspace field, so what I tried was:

```
 ${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

All that happens to me when I use that is that the workspace name is, you guessed it, "${BUILD_NUMBER}" (and I even got a "${BUILD_NUMBER}@2" just for good measure!)

I tried {$BUILD_ID}, same thing (uses that literally, does not substitute the number).

I have the 'allow concurrent builds' turned on.

I'm using pipelines exclusively.

All jobs here, as part of normal execution, cause the slave, non-master host to reboot into an OS that does not have the capability to run slave.jar (indeed, it has no network access at all), so I cannot run the entire pipeline on that host.

All jobs use the following construct somewhere inside them:

```
    tests=Arrays.asList(tests.split("\\r?\n"))
    shellerror=231
    for( line in tests){
```

So let's call an example job 'foo' that loops through a list, as above, that I want to run on 2 different hosts.  The pipeline for that job starts running on master (since the above **for (line in tests)** is REQUIRED to run on a node!)). Then goes back and forth between master and slave, often multiple times.

If I start this job on host A and host B at about the same time, they will BOTH use the workspace ${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${JOB_NAME}, or in my case /var/lib/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/job

Since they write different data to files with the same name in that directory, I'm clearly totally broken immediately.

So, how do I force Jenkins to use a unique workspace EVERY SINGLE JOB?

Or, what???

Other things: pipeline build step version 2.5.1, Jenkins 2.46.2

I've been trying to get the workspace statement ('ws') to work, but that doesn't quite work as I expected either - some files are in the workspace I explicitly name, and some are still in the 'built-in' workspace (workspace/).

I was asked to provide code.  The 'standard' pipeline I use is about 26K bytes, composing about 590 lines.  So, I'm going to GREATLY reduce.  That being said:

```
node("master") { // 1
   ..... lots of stuff....
}  // this matches the "node('master')" above
node(HOST) {
  echo "on $HOST, check what os"
  if (isUnix()) 
      ...some more stuff...
} // end of 'node(HOST)' above
if (isok == 0 ) {
   node("master") { 
      echo "----------------- Running on MASTER 19 $shellerror waiting on boot out of windows ------------"
      sleep 120
      echo "----------------- Leaving MASTER ------------"
   }
}
 ... lots 'o code ...

node(HOST) {
  ... etc 
} // matches the latest 'node HOST' above
node("master") { // 120
    .... code ...
    for( line in tests) {
        ...code...
    }
}
... and on and on and on, switching back and forth from one to the other
```

FWIW, when I tried to make the above use 'ws' so that I could make certain the ws name was unique, I simply added a 'ws wsname' block directly under (almost) every 'node' opening so it was

```
node(name) { ws (wsname) { ..stuff that was in node block before... } }
```

But then I've got two directories to worry about checking - both the 'default' workspace/jobname dir AND the new wsname one.

Comment: Could you please provide some pipeline code to base an answer on? Do you use descriptive (starting with `pipeline` or scripted (starting with `node`) pipelines?

Comment: I've added a lot of code snippet above, as well as a comment about how I tried to make a unique ws name (unfortunately, I cannot create the 'permanent' ws name until I've done some other stuff, but I don't believe I make, need, or use any files that I could have put into the 'default' workspace name - once I've created the 'wsname' I'm ready to start creating, using, etc files.

Comment: Sorry but it's hard to tell what's your question. Do you just need to clean to workspace before each build? Why not using `deletedir()`? Using the same workspace on two different hosts is not supported by Jenkins. Either you have a plugin installed which provides that feature but is unknown to me or your VM setup reuses the same disk across the VMs - which would be really bad and break your jobs.

Comment: The workspace is getting re-used WHILE another build is running, so that 2 ACTIVE but separate builds share the same workspace.  So I'm trying to work around that - either I need to force Jenkins to use some sort of uniqifier (like job number), or I need to get 'ws' to work as I had expected (and understood).   So the question is - HOW do I get Jenkins to not use the same workspace for two different runs that are running at the same time?  (And apologies for hitting 'enter' before I was done with this comment)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a bug in Jenkins. In the background I'm working on a demo of the failure.  Once that is done, where do I go to submit a bug report?

Answer (score 9):

Try using `customWorkspace` node common option:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'node(s)-defined-label'
      customWorkspace "${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }
  }
  stages {
    // Your pipeline logic here
  }
}
```

> **customWorkspace**
>
> A string. Run the Pipeline or individual stage this
>   agent is applied to within this custom workspace, rather than the
>   default. It can be either a relative path, in which case the custom
>   workspace will be under the workspace root on the node, or an absolute
>   path.

#### Edit

Since this doesn't work for your complex pipeline. Maybe try this silly solution:

```
def WORKSPACE = "${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}"

node(HOST) {
   sh(script: "mkdir -p ${WORKSPACE}")
   sh(script: "cd ${WORKSPACE}")
   //Do stuff here
}
```

or if dir() is accessible:

```
def WORKSPACE = "${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}"

node(HOST) {
   sh(script: "mkdir -p ${WORKSPACE}")
   dir(WORKSPACE) {
   //Do stuff here
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this work only for declarative pipelines?  I have a 'for line in tests' (as well as a lot of conditionals) in my pipeline, so I think I have to use the scripted variant.  (I'm going right now to add the 'for (line in tests)' to my code above)

Comment: @RustyCar This option is valid for any `node {}` block (Which I saw you had in your pipeline example), at least it's worth a try (I think it should also work in scripted pipelines). Moreover, I recommend using declarative pipelines it easier to develop and maintain your code.

Comment: unfortunately, my script is pretty involved, and I seem to require a scripted pipeline.  Also, I tried, and 'customWorkspace' is not available in 'node' of a scripted pipeline.  Also, I tried 'simply' wrapping my entire pipeline script in some declarative stuff, and couldn't get it to work.  That is, I removed the 'label' line from your example, and put all my code in the '// your pipeline logic here' area above, but wrapped in a 'script {' block.   (Again, all my if/then/else-ing and the absolutely required 'for(line in tests)' line pretty well forces me in to scripted, IIUC).

Comment: Sorry, dumb question - how do I do an '@Raoslaw Szamszur' to link to him when there is a space in the user name???  Maybe just @Raoslaw, since it might assume I mean someone who has commented here?

Comment: @RustyCar I just type @ and first letter, and them click hint with username I want to reply to. I find it also confusing how to proceed with spaces :). You probably can move your pipeline into declarative one but it's not like you can copy it into  //you pipeline logic here. Maby if you will show me whole pipeline code I can see what can be done (Unless you can't for some reasons).

Comment: Let's split this in to two sub-threads.  I just tried typing '@R (without the '), and nothing happened.  I decided to go read all the links in the help, and found that I should be able to say @raoslaws and it should work. We'll see.  Ah, it did work, it just wasn't obvious.  Ok, so use just the first name, and 'it will just work'.  Sorry about that!

Comment: ok, so now on to the real question - can I send you the actual pipeline script.  I'll have to ask my boss, and if so then we'll have to have a way other than posting it here, as it is 26K, for one, and for the other I'm pretty sure I won't be allowed to make it fully public...

Comment: @RustyCar I totally understand. In fact, I was assuming you're referring to an actual work case. BTW, I've added in edit some silly solutions, maybe they will work.

Comment: well, I tried getting the declarative pipeline to use a scripted subpipe, but for some reason (that I forgot), it didn't work.  I even considered shared libs, but too many restrictions.  Right now I got using 'ws(workspace_name)' inside EVERY node("master") block to work (sort of), but I still have 2 places to look for log files.  I'm going to try to remove the 'customws' setting in the job config to see what happens - if it uses the job number for the workspace then I'm done. (and apologies - I keep forgetting that 'enter' means "SAVE EDITS', not go to new paragraph!)

Answer (score 2):

**Re-read your question** and amending/updating my answer

First let's lay down some terminology (AIUI, which has taken some time).

- Jenkins has a "[job](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/#job-1)" which is holds config, pipeline etc, and will have a specific URL (based on the Jenkins job path and name).
- Jenkins has a "[build](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/#build-1)" which is what you get when you "start a job", and will have a specific URL (based on the `BUILD_ID`).
- Your pipeline code ([declarative or scripted](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#declarative-versus-scripted-pipeline-syntax)) runs within a [build](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/#build-1), and it may have "[stages](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/#stage-1)" and "[steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/#step-1)" in which your code can "do things".  Any thing it does occurs within **a hierarchy of contexts** as coded in the pipeline.   (That may sound kind of obvious, but the notion to remember is that the **contexts** drive everything.  Understanding that can help you arrange your [ws blocks](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#ws-allocate-workspace) as needed).

**Back to your questions**

Q: "how do I either force Jenkins to NOT use the same workspace for two concurrently-running jobs on different hosts" ... [you need] "separate workspace for each run" ... "Jenkins is using the SAME workspace for 2 different, concurrent, jobs on 2 different hosts"

---

### Updated Answer

If by "two concurrently-running jobs" and "run" and "concurrent jobs" you mean "*[Jenkins builds](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/#build-1)*" then you would NOT have overlapping workspaces as they would have different `${JOB_NAME}`s and `${BUILD_ID}`s by definition (even using NFS paths, shared across nodes).

But if by "run" or "build" or "job" you mean some kind of **stage or step or sub-process in your pipeline**, then you must remember they are everything is running *inside the same Jenkins [build](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/#build-1)*.  I think all you need is to invent a token, or use something meaningful, and included it in your `ws` blocks.

Maybe code will say it better:

```
// organize all our workspaces by Jenkins Build
def wsbase = "/some_top_path/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_ID}"

//
// mechanism to get unique ws paths
// a dumb way (integer incremented as we go)
// OR invent a smarter way (some meaningful token or ID)
// Note: this "Build" is "our build" not a "Jenkins build"
//
def dumbID = 0
def getDumbID() { dumbID += 1; return dumbID; }

//def getSmartBuildID(...my_build_config...) {
//   String smartBuildID = ... // call a script? use timestamp?
//   return smartBuildID
//}

node(HOST) {
  echo "on $HOST, check what os"
  if (isUnix()) {
     def buildID = getDumbID()
     // def buildID = getSmartBuildID(..some_build_config...)
     ws("${wsbase}/${buildID}") {
        ...some more stuff... // running in unique ws dir now 
     }
  }
} // end of 'node(HOST)' above
```

---

### My original answer - about 'ws' blocks in general.

You need to use the [ws block](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#ws-allocate-workspace).  If you can guarantee `/some/path/on/all/nodes` is common across all your nodes, then you can just use *one* block across *all* your pipeline:

```
def wspath = "/some/path/on/all/nodes/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_ID}" 

ws(wspath) {
  node("master") {
  ...
  }
  node(HOST) {
  ...
  }
}
```

If you need more than one (e.g. on different nodes) just move the blocks around (they are basically closures so any code inside the block will operate in side that workspace path).  Be sure and use `JOB_NAME` and `BUILD_ID` or else you'll have issues with two builds interfering.

**Note** that for jenkins scripted or declarative pipelines defined in an SCM, to bootstrap that pipeline, Jenkins *must checkout a copy of the pipeline code on the local master node* before any of your pipeline `ws` or `node` code can even run (see [this writeup](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/why-is-my-multibranch-project-cloning-the-whole-repository-on-the-master))

If that is giving you problems, you may need to tweak the `SCM` settings that is retrieving the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

```
'${SOMEVAR}'
```

will not get substituted

```
"${SOMEVAR}"
```

will - this is how groovy strings are being handled
see [groovy string handling](http://grails.asia/groovy-string-tutorial)

so if you have a

```
ws("/some/path/somewhere/${BUILD_ID}")
{
   //something
}
```

on your node in your pipeline Jenkinsfile it should do the trick in this regard

the problem with @2 workspaces can occur when you allow concurrent builds of the project - I had the exact same problem with a custom ws() with @2 - simply disallow concurrent builds or work around that.

Comment: Thanks for the thought - but I see I wasn't clear about where I'd put the ${BUILD_ID} - I'd put it in the 'custom workspace' field in Jenkins config.  I've updated the question to make that more clear (and added my 'ws' issue). However, you DID bring up 'ws', which I've been trying to use, and that results in TWO places that the files go!  You say 'disallow concurrent builds' - I've been assuming that will keep anyone from running the same job on different hosts - is that correct? (We need to run the same job on multiple hosts at the same time)

Answer (score 1):

`customWorkspace` didn't work for me.
What worked:

```
stages {
    stage("SCM (For commit trigger)"){
        steps {
            ws('custom-workspace') { // Because we don't want to switch from the pipeline checkout
                // Generated from http://lstool01:8080/job/Permanent%20Build/pipeline-syntax/
                checkout(xxx)
            }
        }
    }
```