# where is workspace for each build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, installation

I am following this tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_t-hZTX97AI

After implementing it, I don't workspace (ws) like `http://0.0.0.0:8080/job/demo/9/ws/`

What did I miss while setting up Jenkins v 2.171, it is installed remotely on Centos 7?

[image]

Comment: shell command: `pwd`

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera I didn't get you. Whats the solution?

Comment: The question is _where is workspace for each build in jenkins?_  
`echo $FTP_USERNAME; ...; pwd`

Comment: Sorry, I meant why it is not appearing where arrow in pointing in picture. I went through these links but didnt quite get how to implement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207067/jenkins-how-to-run-builds-in-unique-directories https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-users/i-8gTNug3ck/N3m1d49EGgAJ https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/MPmGIDAhmaY

Comment: Sorry, I can't undertand, the video is about _Using environment variables_

Comment: Video I understood, I just want to have a separate workspace for each build. It used to come where it is pointing in picture but now with new Jenkins set up its not there. Seems I am missing something.